# Unable to run Bitmap sample code for Android

Tags: android

I am trying to run the sample from : 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

However I encountered lots of errors like:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
BuildConfig cannot be resolved to a variable    ImageGridFragment.java  /ImageGridActivity/src/com/example/android/bitmapfun/ui line 124    Java Problem
```

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
SuppressLint cannot be resolved to a type   Utils.java  /ImageGridActivity/src/com/example/android/bitmapfun/util   line 99 Java Problem
```

I ran thru Google but could get nothing. Adjusted the android build target to `4.0.3 (15)` but still no clue. Anyone ran this sample successfully?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:
1.Create a new class:

```
package com.example.android.bitmapfun;

public class BuildConfig {
public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

2.Comment the lines that contain "SuppressLint":

```
//import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
//    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

Answer (score 2):

Android developer tools r17 brings a feature to Eclipse where a class is auto built at build-time, called BuildConfig, which contains a constant that can be used by the app developer to sense whether the build is a dev build or a production build. This feature appears to be in the Eclipse integration support, so when using IntelliJ, this useful feature is not available

In gen folder with R.java there should be BuildConfig.java if your program compiled successfully.

```
/** Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */
package com.example.android.bitmapfun;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and try to launch it again.

It worked for me.

Comment: Tried to clean and restart eclipse. Even re-import the project but still having the errors.

Comment: How did you import the project ?

Comment: My bad, i create a New Android project after downloading the zip file. Immediately errors appear. Was it the same for you?

Comment: I unzipped the folder and then I created a new Android projet from existing source. I got the errors but cleaning made them disappear.

Answer (score 0):

For me also it is not running directly import to eclipse. Just i put comments which lines is showing errors then it is working fine for me. May be it is not a right answer but we can see the application functionality by running the code so i did like that.